# Query to find people with multiple names

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a fairly big project that allows users of my client's site to search for people they used to know who might've changed their names, primarily due to marriage. Basically, users sign up with all the names they've ever used and the data gets entered into a MySQL database. The next step is actually creating the search, which allows users to put in the names they remember someone by.

This is an example registration in the database:

```
username first0 first1 first2 first3 first4
(email)  Lisa   John   Frank  Sam    Smith
```

Right now, my query looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM NAMES
WHERE (
    `names`.`first0` IN ("Lisa", "Sam", "")
    AND `names`.`first1` IN ("Lisa", "Sam", "")
    AND `names`.`first2` IN ("Lisa", "Sam", "")
    AND `names`.`first3` IN ("Lisa", "Sam", "")
    AND `names`.`first4` IN ("Lisa", "Sam", "")
```

**Substitute out the exact names there for data entered in the search form.

This query doesn't work because first2 = `Frank`, which isn't included in the list. If a person doesn't know every name someone entered in the database, everything breaks.

However, I don't think I want to use OR statements, because I don't want all the results where a name matches `Lisa` to be returned if someone puts `Lisa` as just one of the names.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

Comment: This looks like a poor schema design. Essentially, whenever you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2) consider whether your design is optimal.

Comment: @Strawberry It's all pretty bad; I'm just trying to get something that works decent enough for now. Would a better schema help me on the path to solving this problem? There are 10 columns for each piece of information a person can fill out...

Comment: I'd say if someone has used that many names of varying gender assignment/neutrality, they probably don't *want* to be found! :)

Comment: Help? A better schema would trivialise the problem you presently face

Comment: What actually is the use of the five different "first" columns? Are they supposed to be first names? But why do you need 5 different columns?

Comment: @Strawberry what kind of schema would you use for this? I'm pretty new to SQL and databases in general; I thought this would be good enough when I was designing this. Guess not :P

Comment: @KoalaYeung it's so people can find their friends who have changed their names over the years. I should've used last names as the example; there are 10 columns per piece of information a person can enter. Say you knew Mark when his last name was Smith, but he changed it to Maxwell and you still want to find him. You can enter the city you know him from, his previous names, and then have a shot at finding who you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're constrained unnecessarily here. Consider instead:

```
User
UserId, OtherData

UserNames
UserId, Name, Kind
```

Data like:

```
UserId, OtherData
1, Blahblah

UserId, Name, Type
1, Lisa, First 
1, Jane, Middle
1, Smith, Last   
1, Leese, First
1, Jones, Last
```

Lisa Jane Smith, also known as Leese, married and changed name to Lisa Jane Jones

If you present the website user with a "Enter any number of names and indicate their kind" you can then run a query that finds the userids that have all the name kinds mentioned

This can be as simple as dynamically joining, or doing conditional aggregation

Eg if the web user enters "Leese" as firstname and "Jones" as lastname then you can:

```
SELECT UserID FROM UserNames 
WHERE 
  (name = 'Leese' AND type = 'First') OR
  (name = 'Jones' AND type = 'Last')
GROUP BY
  UserID 
HAVING count(*) = 2 --2 is the number of names entered, leese and jones.  If your where clause had 5 names, this would be 5
```

Or you can use a join approach (and this for if the web user enters 3 names/kinds):

```
SELECT u1.UserID 
FROM
  UserNames u1 
  INNER JOIN Usernames u2 ON u1.UserID = u2.UserID
  INNER JOIN Usernames u3 ON u1.UserID = u3.UserID
WHERE 
  u1.name = 'Leese' AND u1.type = 'First' AND
  u2.name = 'Jones' AND u2.type = 'Last' AND
  u3.name = 'Smith' AND u3.type = 'Last' AND
```

When you go to form your dynamic queries, *don't* concatenate the values into SQL. Just because you're making a query dynamic built is not an excuse to throw parameterization out of the window. You build the SQL by concatenating together the SQL string with parameter placeholders in and then give the parameters values separately

Pseudocode (i don't know php) in a language that interpolates its strings with {placeholders}:

```
string fromclause = ""
string whereclause = ""
for i = 0 to webrequest.form.values.length - 1

  string name = webrequest.form.values[i].name
  string type = webrequest.form.values[i].type


  if i == 0 then
    fromclause = fromclause + "Usernames u{i}"
  else
    fromclause = fromclause + " INNER JOIN Usernames u{i} ON u1.UserID = u{i}.UserID

  whereclause = whereclause + " u{i}.Name = @paramName{i} AND u{i}.type = @paramType{i}"

  sqlcommand.parameters.add("@paramName{i}", name)
  sqlcommand.parameters.add("@paramType{i}", type)

next i

sqlcommand.commandtext = "SELECT UserID FROM {fromclause} WHERE {whereclause}"
```

You finish up with a sql command that is all parameterized and the parameters are all given values..

Comment: I like this a lot better than what I had... Will likely mix it with Strawberry's answer below, but your query looks right on point. Super helpful, thanks!

Comment: Added some advice on how to use the sql too

Answer (score 1):

A normalised schema might look like this...

```
id username first
 1 (email)  Lisa   
 2 (email)  John   
 3 (email)  Frank  
 4 (email)  Sam    
 5 (email)  Smith
```

Comment: Hmmmm... I think I understand what you're getting at. In my database, the primary key is actually the email; that's what I've been using to link everything together. To clarify, you're suggesting seperate rows for each piece of information entered?

Answer (score 0):

With your current schema, a statement like this would probably work:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `names`
WHERE (
    `names`.`first0` = "Lisa" OR
    `names`.`first1` = "Lisa" OR
    `names`.`first2` = "Lisa" OR
    `names`.`first3` = "Lisa" OR
    `names`.`first4` = "Lisa"
) AND (
    `names`.`first0` = "Sam" OR
    `names`.`first1` = "Sam" OR
    `names`.`first2` = "Sam" OR
    `names`.`first3` = "Sam" OR
    `names`.`first4` = "Sam"
)
```

But as other people point out, you should have a different normalized schema like this:

```
CREATE old_firstnames (
  username VARCHAR(255),
  firstname VARCHAR(255),
  timestamp DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (username, firstname, timestamp)
)
```

Your data is then probably be:

```
username firstname timestamp
(email)  Lisa      1998-02-01
(email)  John      2001-03-02
(email)  Frank     2006-01-04
(email)  Sam       2009-11-13
(email)  Smith     2018-09-01
```

And you can search your user by:

```sql
SELECT * FROM old_firstnames n1
LEFT JOIN old_firstname n2 ON (n1.username = n2.username)
WHERE n1.firstname = "Lisa" AND n2.firstname = "Sam"
```

Comment: No point using LEFT JOIN in this cause; `WHERE n2 =` makes it behave as INNER

Comment: You SQL skill is better than mine.